# Retrieve Information from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let suppose this is my data set

```
[
      {
        id: 1,
        roomId: 'abc',
        type: 'user-message',
        message: 'I am a message',
        date: DATE_ISO_FORMAT
      }, {
        id: 2,
        roomId: 'abc',
        type: 'bot-message',
        message: 'I am a bot message',
        date: DATE_ISO_FORMAT
      }, {
        id: 3,
        roomId: 'abc',
        type: 'user-message',
        message: 'I am another message',
        date: DATE_ISO_FORMAT
      }, {
        id: 4,
        roomId: 'abc',
        type: 'system-message',
        message: 'I am a system message',
        date: DATE_ISO_FORMAT
      }, {
        id: 5,
        roomId: 'abc',
        type: 'bot-message',
        message: 'I am another bot message',
        date: DATE_ISO_FORMAT
      }, {
        id: 6,
        roomId: 'xyz',
        type: 'user-message',
        message: 'I am user message from another room',
        date: DATE_ISO_FORMAT
      }
]
```

I want to retrieve the latest message of each `roomId` where the last message is not `bot-message`, so if the last message was `bot-message` I would want to get the second latest message where the message might of type `user-message` or `system-message`. I know this will be done with some sort of aggregation, any idea or starting point where I can start this from.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match:{type:{$ne:'bot-message'}}},
    {$sort:{date:-1}},
    {
     $group:
         {_id: "$roomId","date": { $first: "$date" },
        "type":{$first:"$type"},"message":{$first:"$message"}}
     }
    ])
```

Comment: With a little changes, I could make this work. Thank you. This helped a lot in setting the query.